# A function as an argument in Julia (best practice / code design)

Tags: design-patterns, julia, function-pointers, functor

What is the best/most elegant code design in the Julia programming language for the following problem:

The modules `mod1`, `mod2`, `mod3`, ... implement a complicated function `fun(a,b,c)`, which calculates and returns a matrix `M`.

A function `foo` of my program needs to calculate the matrix `M` repeatably via the function `fun` with varying input parameters `a,b,c`. However, the user of my program can specify which module is used for `fun`. Note, that the user is no programmer and only wants to type something like `julia program.jl` and specifies the used module with a string like "MODULE = mod2" in some input file.

The most naive and inelegant solution would probably be via if...elseif...

```
function foo(...
[...]
    if SpecifiedModule == "mod1"
        M = mod1.fun(a,b,c)
    elseif SpecifiedModule == "mod2"
        M = mod2.fun(a,b,c)
    SpecifiedModule == "mod3"
        M = mod3.fun(a,b,c)
    end
    # process M
```

An alternative way would be to use function-pointers. Or even `functors` as known from C++?

What is best practice in Julia for this case? Is there a way to get rid of this ugly if..elseif... code?

PS: there are similarities to the case of finding an optimized value of a function, like in the module Optim.jl (https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl/). If I am not wrong, a user specified function `f` is passed as an argument to the `optimize(f, ...)` function.

Comment: Why not just let the users directly use `mod1.fun`? The API that you're proposing just appears to be a clunkier, type-unstable way of doing the same thing, unless I have misunderstood some details.

Comment: Good point, but the result of `fun` is not the result of the program, it‘s just a intermediate result which is processed by my program. Alternatively, is there some way to let the user decide if my program loads mod1 or mod2 … . Like  `if SpecifiedModule == „mod2“ then using mod2` (clearly not valide Julia code) . And later I just call `fun(a,b,c)` .

Comment: Are the types returned by `Mod1.fun`, `Mod2.fun` etc guaranteed to be identical?

Comment: Yes, guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Identical return types

If the return types are guaranteed to be identical, you could use [Match.jl](https://github.com/JuliaServices/Match.jl) and pattern match over `Symbol`s or enums.

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("Match")
using Match

function fun(args, SpecifiedModule::Symbol)
    M = @match SpecifiedModule begin
        :mod1 => Mod1.fun(args...)
        :mod2 => Mod2.fun(args...)
        :mod3 => Mod3.fun(args...)
        _ => Mod1.fun(args)  # default behaviour, error handling etc
    end
end

M1 = fun(args, :mod1)  # call with Mod1
M2 = fun(args, :mod2)  # call with Mod2
# ... and so on
```

This should work fine if the return types of `fun` are guaranteed to be the same, else there will be type instabilities.

### General return types, but module known at compile time

If the module name is guaranteed to be known at compile, you can use `Val` with symbols to use Julia's multiple dispatch/function overloading as a pattern matching mechanism.

```
get_module(::Val{:mod1}) = Mod1
get_module(::Val{:mod2}) = Mod2
get_module(::Val{:mod3}) = Mod3
# ... and so on


function fun(args, SpecifiedModule)
    get_module(SpecifiedModule).fun(args)
end

fun(args, Val(:mod1))  # calls Mod1.fun
fun(args, Val(:mod2))  # calls Mod2.fun
```

Arguments to `Val` can only be compile-time known `isbitstype` values, so you cannot assign e.g. `:mod1` to a variable and pass it. [Some exposition on `Val`](https://loonatick-src.github.io/pages/intro/) (full disclosure, I am the author).

## `foo` as a higher order function

Just as in the example of Optim.jl, you could let users pass an arbitrary function `f` like `foo(a, b, c, Mod1.fun)`. This is a natural choice when the input function needs to be somewhat general, such as some function that you want to optimize, differentiate etc. I am not sure about your particular use case, but if you want to restrict the users' choices to a specific set of functions, then it would be better to avoid this.